# Convert CSV object to JSON object in Node

Tags: node.js, json, csv, npm

I am trying to convert a CSV object to a JSON object line by line. I don't want to convert the CSV file to JSON because my file has over 4 million objects.

Also, I am using csvjson module, but I don't think you can convert a CSV object to JSON. I think you can only convert a CSV file to JSON

```js
const lineReader = require('line-reader');
const csvjson = require("csvjson"); 

lineReader.eachLine('example.csv', function(line) {
    const options = {
        delimiter : ',' , // optional
        quote     : '"' // optional
    };

    let jsonObject= csvjson.toObject(line,options);
    console.log(jsonObject) //prints []
});
```

Comment: And, what exactly is the problem you want help with.  You show some code.  What's the issue with that code?

Comment: If you run the code on a csv. it prints "[ ]" for each line, as shown above. The problem is converting a csv object to a json object

Comment: Can you show some sample data from the CSV file to make this into a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Looking at the doc for `csvjson`, I don't think this type of use is what `csvjson.toObject()` is for.  It looks like `csvjson.toObject()` expects to get a whole CSV file that would contain column names and multiple rows of data.  I don't think it knows what to do with one line of data.  It is not clear to me yet that the `csvjson` module supports this type of access.  It might have to be done using the stream interface (partly shown in the last code example in the doc), but that would take some experimentation to figure out how to intercept each line of data.

Comment: I'm guessing there's probably a better csv module with specific examples for how to read and process a huge csv data file line by line.

Answer (score 0):

To process things line by line, it looks to me like you will need a different csv module that supports incremental stream parsing and outputs actual Javascript objects line by line (you want javascript objects, not JSON).

There are a ton of CSV modules on NPM, many of which have some level of stream support.  This one [`cvs-reader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-reader) seems to offer the right capabilities and works for me in a simple demo program.  I'm sure there are other modules also with similar capabilities.

Here's a working demonstration with cvs-reader.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csvReader = require('csv-reader');

// All of these arguments are optional.
const options = { 
    skipEmptyLines: true,
    asObject: true,             // convert data to object
    parseNumbers: true, 
    parseBooleans: true, 
    trim: true 
};

const csvStream = new csvReader(options);
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('example.csv', 'utf8');

readStream.on('error', err => {
     console.log(err);
     csvStream.destroy(err);
}).pipe(csvStream).on('error', err => {
    console.error(err);
}).on('data', (data) => {
    // outputs an object containing a set of key/value pair representing a line found in the csv file.
    console.log(data);    // {firstname: "John", lastname: "Bundy", state: "CA"}
}).on('end', () => {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks!